# Displaying my own analytics data to unauthenticated users

Tags: django, authentication, google-visualization, google-analytics-api

I am writing this question after considerable investigation into this matter.
I have gone through Google's easy dashboards (gadash JS library), superProxy and plain analytics API, and couldn't find the best solution for my needs, although I can't believe my needs are so uncommon. 
This is why I am turning to you, I have got a feeling I am missing something.

My requirement:

1. Display my own analytics account data to users on my website, preferably with Google's chart API or ga-dash, to resemble google analytics views as much as possible.
2. Users will not have to take part in authentication with Google API
3. Each user has his own query which is built dynamically !! (this is probably why superProxy cannot work for me because I think you need to manually set the queries in advance)
4. I use django-python as the basis for my website

problems with solutions I tried:

1. GAdash library  - the problem is that each user has to be authenticated, and shown their own data, meaning they need access to my profile- that's simply not what I am looking for. It works great, but only for me. On the other hand if there was a way to make my profile truly public...
2. superProxy - sounds like a solution for this need exactly, however I don't think that you can programmatically set the queries.
3. I did find a way to retrieve the data for a query on the server side using my own credential which is a bit hacky, I am still missing that JS library which will parse this XML on the client side and display it as charts.

EDIT:
I ended up using Mark's solution (embeddedanalytics), since I could not find a better, easier solution.

Other alternatives were: 
1. superProxy (lacking the ability to dynamically, programmatically loading new queries)
2. gaDash library - requires authentication from each user
3. Implement my own server side querying, and display to the user with some js graphics library - which would require considerable work on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [www.embeddedanalytics.com](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com).  This is a platform/service which will do exactly what you are looking to do (*disclosure - I work with them*).

We also support your requirement that each user have its own dynamically built query.  This is what we call our CMS Integration version.  Are you trying to create a dashboard system for a CMS system you have built?